# Voltage and resistors

Tags: resistors, raspberry-pi

I put a 100R resistor to the output pin of a Raspberry Pi Pico and the amps went down from around 50mA to 15mA, but when I check voltage it stays the same at 3.3V.

[image: schematic]

Am I doing something wrong when measuring with my multimeter?

Comment: To the ground of the Py Pico. When I set the output pin f the Pico to send power and put the red probe on the out pin and the black probe on the ground pin I get 3.3v and around 50mA. When I connect the resistor to the out pin and put the red probe at the other side of the resistor the amps drop to 15 but the voltage stays the same.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? We can't say why something you expect does not happen.

Comment: For PC817 it says I need 1.2-1.4 volts at 20mA. To get the resistor I did (3.3v-1.2v)/0.02.  Everything works but I'm afraid that the voltage is to high I will destroy the opto-coupler at any moment.

Comment: @MySK - Hi, FYI I copied your schematic image from external hosting (which can disappear after a while) to the SE image hosting. Use Ctrl+G (or click the "mountains" icon) when editing Q&A to start the image upload dialog. || As you are new here, see the [tour] & [help] as site rules differ from typical forums.

Comment: Measure the voltage across the 100R resistor.

Comment: Why would the optocoupler be destroyed?

Comment: If you previously connected the optocoupler to this same output without the current-limiting resistor, you may have damaged the optocoupler. Try a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You should always put a current meter in *series* with what you are trying to measure.

You have been measuring the short-circuit current of the output, which is not good for the output and (if you had a source with beefier capability) will blow the fuse in your meter, at best.

A 100Ω series resistor will limit the short circuit current to 33mA and with the PC817 LED in series it will be more like 28mA, rather high. I would suggest no more than 10-15mA which means a resistor in the 160Ω range.

If you want to measure the current the best way is to measure the voltage across the resistor (meter in voltage mode, of course) and divide that reading by the resistance (you can measure the resistor value first, out of circuit, if you don't trust the markings or want to be more accurate than the tolerance). The reason for this is that even if you put it in series, the meter will affect the current a bit, making it lower, and that's not only introducing error but it's on the less-than-conservative side if you're close to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You used Ohm's law to calculate the resistor value how much it drops voltage at 20mA, so it will drop that amount at 20mA.

If you simply measure voltage with no current through resistor, it will also drop no voltage.